# How can I redirect images in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have two issues:

1) I am trying to redirect images from one url to another url, but it's not working

2) I have some images which are not now present in my website. When I try to open that URL, it is redirecting `404 Not Found Nginx` . I want to redirect it to home page.

I have tried the following codes

```
###### BEGIN WP_OPTIMIZE_BY_XTRAFFIC_CONFIGS_WP-OPTIMIZE-BY-XTRAFFIC ######
Options -Indexes
###### END WP_OPTIMIZE_BY_XTRAFFIC_CONFIGS_WP-OPTIMIZE-BY-XTRAFFIC ######
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
ErrorDocument 404 https://tabc.com (Not Working)
#Also Tried this, not working
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(test\.html|\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /tabc.com  [L]
RedirectPermanent /wp-content/uploads/image.gif http://www.tabc.com/path/ 
</IfModule>


# END WordPress

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php54” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php54 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: Are you using **Nginx** or **Apache**?

Comment: I believe it should be apache, however I am not sure for this.

Comment: I am asking you because of this "404 Not Found NGINX" message. You should ask your host provider.If you are using **NGINX** then your .htaccess rules will not work unless there is "conversion" of these rules.

Comment: okay. so the above codes can only work for apache ?

Comment: I suggest to use the "default" .htaccess from WordPress by adding only this line `Redirect permanent "/one" "http://example.com/two"` for testing. If this doesn't work you should check is the Apache Module **mod_alias** is enabled by your host provider.

Comment: That also is not working

Comment: Does something like this `Redirect 301 /images/123.jpg http://example.com/images/456.jpg` works?

Comment: No that is also not working. Please help me to understand, suppose if I am using Nginx instead of Apache, will these rules will be valid?

Comment: If you are using **NGINX** none of these rules will work unless are converted to **NGINX**. Also have a look at this https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx

Comment: Okay. Yes I have confirmed, it is using nginx. So could you please tell me how to do the same in Nginx as I have written that for Apache. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
# nginx configuration

location = /favicon.ico {
}

location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
  }
}

location /images/123.jpg {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ http://example.com/images/abc.jpg redirect;
}
```

You should also read this https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/ and use this https://winginx.com/en/htaccess

Comment: What exactly is not working? Edit your question and show us your current **nginx configuration**.